# var keyword not always working?

Tags: c#, var, propertydescriptor

C#, VS 2010. Somebody, please explain why I can't use `var` in my code below!

```
var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(adapter);

// error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayName'
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    string name = prop.DisplayName;
}

// No error
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
{
    string name = prop.DisplayName;
}
```

`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` returns a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` with instances of `PropertyDescriptor`. Why can't the compiler see this?

Comment: If you replace var with PropertyDescriptorCollection does it work?

Comment: I'm guessing `PropertyDescriptorCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor>`, which throws the type inference. Why the latter works I have no idea though.

Comment: Thats one of the cases where i wouldn't use var. I only use var when the type before the name would be redundant. Otherwise it hides stuff like this.

Comment: @millimoose Because foreach will cast every instance and throws an invalidcastexception if it couldn't cast it.

Comment: A side note, on a matter of taste and readability: `var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(adapter);` causes the reader to have to know or find out the type of the `var`, rather than denote the type explicitly which would be more sensible, and use `var` where the type is obvious (i.e. `var thing = new ExplicitThing()`).

Comment: @dowhilefor On the other hand, using an explicit type inside `foreach` hides a cast that can fail at runtime. Not sure what is worse, the hidden cast or the unclear type.

Comment: @dowhilefor Ah, I didn't know that. (I'm a Java expatriate and their equivalent of `foreach` doesn't work that way.)

Comment: @GrantThomas That's a somewhat pedantic point, seeing as "finding out" can be done by mousing over `prop` in Visual Studio.  I wouldn't avoid `var` for that reason much like I don't avoid ambiguity that's resolved by syntax highlighting.

Comment: @CodesInChaos i'm sorry that wasn't clear of me, i didn't meant the cast in the foreach, i meant the first var. Usually i use var when the type is absolutely clear like with new and casts. Also if i have a list of elements, where the type is clearly visible i use var in a foreach.

Comment: @millimoose Considering putting my hand on my mouse is actually an effort detracting from my productivity, let alone having to archaically drag it over the screen, no, that's an added process one can do without.

Comment: @millimoose (to your first comment) Technically, it's the public method `GetEnumerator` which is examined to get the element type of the `foreach` in this case, so interfaces are not considered when a public `GetEnumerator()` method exists. See my new answer for details.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` returns a class that only has a [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection.getenumerator.aspx) implementation that returns the non-generic `IEnumerator`. The type of its [`Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) property is `object` - and that's the only type the compiler can infer, so that's the type your `prop` variable will be.

The second `foreach` that uses `PropertyDescriptor` instead of `var` as the type of `prop` actually performs a conversion from `object` to `PropertyDescriptor`.

Assume this code:

```
PropertyDescriptor x = // get from somewhere;
object o = x;
PropertyDescriptor y = (PropertyDescriptor)o;
```

The same is happening in the second `foreach` loop for each item.

---

You could add a `Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()` to get a generic `IEnumerable<T>` with an implementation of `GetEnumerator` that returns `IEnumerator<T>`. If you do this, you can use `var` in the `foreach` loop:

```
var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(adapter).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();

// No error
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    string name = prop.DisplayName;
}
```

Comment: To be very pedantic, before the compiler even cares about `IEnumerable` and `IEnumareble<T>`, it checks if there exists a public instance method `GetEnumerator()`, and if that method would work (return type must have some specific members). This is the case here. So actually it is the return type of the public method which makes `var` mean `object`, and the interfaces are not considered. (It's easy to write a class which implements only non-generic `IEnumerable` (explicit interface implementation) but whose public `GetEnumerator()` method returns something type-safe.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thanks for your comment. I tried to integrate it in my answer, please check.

Comment: Great. I checked it and decided to make a minor edit to your answer so hopefully now it's a little better. Maybe I will write my own answer with more details.

Comment: (Now I did write an answer like that.)

Answer (score 8):

PropertyDescriptorCollection only implements `IEnumerable`, so the compiler only knows that elements contained in it are of type `object`. When you specify the type in your foreach loop, the compiler will insert a cast to the type you specify.

You can use the `Cast<T>` extension method on `IEnumerable` to cast each item to a given type:

```
using System.Linq;
...
IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = props.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` returns a [`PropertyDescriptorCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which does not implement `IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor>` but only `IEnumerable`.

Therefore `prop` is just an `object` which has no `DisplayName` property at compile time.

So you have to specify the type explicitely in the `foreach`:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
{
    string name = prop.DisplayName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`PropertyDescriptorCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection.aspx) implements `IEnumerable` but **not** `IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor>` so all that can be seen is that it enumerates `object`s. So that's what `var` infers.

`foreach` has always had the ability to perform an hidden cast to whatever its iteration variable type is, so that's why the second version works. It had to work this way in the pre-generics era.

Answer (score 2):

What I am going to cover here is described in formal detail in the C# Language Specification, section *"The foreach statement"*.

When you use an *implicitly typed iteration variable* in a `foreach` statement (that is, `var`), which is a very good thing to do, here's how the compiler finds out what `var` is to mean.

First it checks the **compile-time** type of the expression to the right-hand side of the `in` keyword in your `foreach`. (If it's an array type like `PropertyDescriptor[]` or `PropertyDescriptor[,,,]` or similar, a special rule applies. There's another rule if it's `dynamic`.)

It checks if that type has a method called precisely `GetEnumerator` (with that capitalization) with an overload that is `public`, non-static, non-generic and takes in zero parameters. If so, it examines the return type of this method (we're still talking compile-time types here, so it's the declared return type). This type must have a method `MoveNext()` and a property `Current`. It then takes the property type of `Current` and uses that as the *element type*. So your `var` stands for this type.

To show how this works, I wrote this:

```
    class Foreachable
    {
        public MyEnumeratorType GetEnumerator()  // OK, public, non-static, non-generic, zero arguments
        {
            return default(MyEnumeratorType);
        }

    }

    struct MyEnumeratorType
    {
        public int Current
        {
            get { return 42; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    static class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var coll = new Foreachable();

            foreach (var x in coll)   // mouse-over 'var' to see it translates to 'int'
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

You see that `var` becomes `int` (`System.Int32`) in my case because of the type of the `Current` property.

Now in your case the compile-time type of `props` is [`PropertyDescriptorCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection.aspx). The type has a [`GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection.getenumerator.aspx) which is public and non-static as required. The return type of the method is seen to be [`System.Collections.IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) in this case. This `IEnumerator` type has the required [`Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) property, and the type of this property is seen to be `Object`. So there it comes from!

(A lot of class originally written for .NET 1 have this design. No strong typing with `foreach` on them.)

Note that *if* a type implements `IEnumerable<out T>` (generic) or/and `IEnumerable` (non-generic), and *if* one of these two interfaces is implemented "implicitly" (normally, not explicit interface implementation), then the type surely has a `GetEnumerator` which is public and non-static, non-generic and take zero arguments. So that public method will be used by `foreach`.

Now if the compile-time type of the expression you're trying to `foreach` does not have a public instance method `GetEnumerator()` (no type parameters and no value parameters), the compiler will see if the type is converible to `IEnumerable<Something>` or (else) to `IEnumerable`. Since `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T`, there will often be many `Something` so that `IEnumerable<Something>` applies. This is explained a little confusingly in the spec (version 5.0). For it is also possible that the type looks like this:

```
    class Foreachable : IEnumerable<Animal>, IEnumerable<Giraffe>
    {
        // lots of stuff goes here
    }
```

for reference types `Animal` and `Giraffe` with the expected inheritance relation, and it is not clear from the spec **version 5.0** that this class (compile-time type) can not be `foreach`ed.